# Marking duplicates records in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to mark duplicate records, however I get wrong reassignment on few on them and I don't know why.

Data:

=`FirstName | LastName | Company | Group | Status | ID`

```
      x    |    x     |     x   | NULL  | NULL   | 1
      x    |    x     |     x   | NULL  | NULL   | 2
```

Then I run this query to find matches on FirstName, LastName, Company 
and join it back to the main table to mark the records:

```
    with d as (
select ID, FirstName, LAstName, Company, row_number() over (partition by FirstName,LastName, Company order by FirstName,LastName, Company) as nr
from [dbo].xx) 

Update b
set Status = 'S'
, Group = d.DQ_ID
from xx as b inner join d on
b.FirstName = d.FirstName and 
b.LastNAme = d.LastName and
b.Company = d.Company
where d.nr = 1
```

And then Update the Main Record with P

```
Update b
set Status = 'P'
from xx as b
where b.ID = b.Group
GO
```

What I expect:

=`FirstName | LastName | Company | Group | Status | ID`

```
      x    |    x     |     x   | 1     |  P     | 1
      x    |    x     |     x   | 1     |  S     | 2
```

What I get:

=`FirstName | LastName | Company | Group | Status | ID`

```
      x    |    x     |     x   | 2     |  S     | 1
      x    |    x     |     x   | 1     |  S     | 2
```

I am working on about 1M records - and it only happen to some of them!

Comment: The group column identifies each different set of firstname, lastname and company?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
;with d as (

select 
ID, 
FirstName, 
LAstName, 
Company, 
row_number() over (
    partition by FirstName,LastName, Company 
    order by Id asc -- this was done to keep ordering as per ID
    ) as nr
from [dbo].xx
) ,
e as 
(select * from d where nr=1)
-- e was created to only take the nr=1 rows which will be joined to all similar records
Update b
set Status = case when e.DQ_ID = b.DQ_ID  then 'P' else 'S' end
 -- the set case logic ensures that matching ids get P else S
, Group = e.DQ_ID
from xx as b 
    inner join e on
        b.FirstName = e.FirstName and 
        b.LastNAme = e.LastName and
        b.Company = e.Company
```

Comment: - Woah - it is working :O. Thanks! Could you tell me what was wrong in my query, please? SO I don't make the same mistake in the future?

Comment: you should only join back the distinct records from the original cte `d` in inner join, because matching criteria will join one record from `d` with all record having same name and company. Since we choose 1 st record from d in matching, so update can be done easily with a case statement.

Answer (score 1):

Can try with the following:

```
;WITH RankedData AS
(
    SELECT
        T.ID,
        T.[Group],
        T.Status,
        T.FirstName,
        T.LastName,
        T.Company,
        GroupRanking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.FirstName, T.LastName, T.Company ORDER BY T.ID ASC)
    FROM
        dbo.xx AS T
)
UPDATE T SET
    [Group] = N.ID,
    Status = CASE WHEN T.GroupRanking = 1 THEN 'P' ELSE 'S' END
FROM
    RankedData AS T
    INNER JOIN RankedData AS N ON
        T.FirstName = N.FirstName AND
        T.LastName = N.LastName AND
        T.Company = N.Company AND
        N.GroupRanking = 1
```

Keep in mind that the `INNER JOIN` will join on not null names and companies, will have to keep in mind if you have nulls on those columns.

Comment: Your query works as well - but I had to use the original ID to use it as a group.

Comment: @Lemon oh, didn't know you needed to keep the ID for each group, I've edited the query.

Comment: After you changed the query - it is not working. Last join is failing.

Comment: @Lemon sorry, forgot to add the proper columns inside the CTE. Edited now.